# How to Add an Icon at the End of Truncated Text in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, cross-platform

I am working on a Flutter app and I'm trying to achieve a specific UI effect. I want to display an icon at the end of a text that is truncated after a maximum of 3 lines.

How can I achieve this?

Please refer to the attached image for reference.[image]